# Is there a faster way to do this loop instr function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large data set (ie 100,000+ rows).  I need to loop through the values in one or more columns and if instr conditions are **TRUE**, then I will update another column's value to 1.  However, the first loop function i wrote takes too long to run (I forced quit after five minutes).  Is there a way to write this function that will execute faster?

I tried using multiple if/then instead of a single if/then but that didn't work.

```
Sub bucketup()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Set SrchRng = Range("Data!D4:D" & LastRow)

For Each cel In SrchRng

    '''''' Check 1 ''''''

        'Check 1 Sub 1'
        If cel.Offset(0, 12).Value = "North" AND (InStr(1, UCase(cel.Value), "SUBSTRING&#0174;") > 0 Or InStr(1, UCase(cel.Value), "SUBSTRING®") > 0 Or InStr(1, UCase(cel.Value), "SUBSTRINGÂ®") > 0) Then
            cel.Offset(0, 15).Value = 1
        End If

Next cel

End Sub
```

The expected result was that for every row `where column P = "North"` and column D contained one of the substrings, Column S would be set to 1.  The actual result is an indefinitely long query whose time to execute makes it unusable.

Comment: If there is not too much of data then I will use `.Find` to first search for **SUBSTRING**, considering it is a part of 3 matching conditions and then do the rest of the comparisions. If there is too much of data then I will copy the data to an array and then search for **SUBSTRING** and then do the rest of the comparisions. Trying to match all conditions at the same time will slow down your loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try working through an array that was bulk loaded from the worksheet instead of looping through the worksheet's cells.

You should also 'short circuit' your selection criteria. Your primary comparison is whether column P is *North*. I think it's reasonable to assume that the possibilities are either 1 in 4 (N in N, S, E, W) or 1 in 8 (N in N, NE, NW, S, SE, SW, E, W). If you put all selection criteria into the same If statement then you are searching for *SUBSTRINGx* many more times than you have to. Break out the check for *North* into a separate If statement and only continue checking if a match is found.

```
Option Explicit

Sub bucketup()

    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
    Dim searchArr As Variant, resultArr As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)

        searchArr = .Range(.Cells(4, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 12)).Value2
        ReDim resultArr(LBound(searchArr, 1) To UBound(searchArr, 1), 1 To 1)

        For i = LBound(searchArr, 1) To UBound(searchArr, 1)

            If searchArr(i, 13) = "North" Then
                If InStr(1, searchArr(i, 1), "SUBSTRING&#0174;", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
                   InStr(1, searchArr(i, 1), "SUBSTRING®", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
                   InStr(1, searchArr(i, 1), "SUBSTRINGÂ®", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    resultArr(i, 1) = 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        .Cells(4, "S").Resize(UBound(resultArr, 1), UBound(resultArr, 2)) = resultArr

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, @user11314630. I think the upading of Column S should be `.Cells(4, "S").Resize(UBound(resultArr, 1), UBound(resultArr, 2)) = resultArr`.  Question: given that my results array will be multidimensional, how do I populate additional columns (ie Column T, U, V)?

Comment: Thanks. I switched things halfway through and apparently missed that change. If they are going to be right beside S then make resultArr's second rank 1 to 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this approach, see which works best for you.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Find_Cell_Value()

  Dim c As Range
  Dim firstaddress As String
  Dim Lastrow As Long
  Dim Look as Worksheet

  Set Look = ActiveSheet

  Lastrow = Look.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

  With Look.Range("P2:P" & Lastrow)
  Set c = .Find("North", LookIn:=xlValues)

  If Not c Is Nothing Then
  firstaddress = c.Address

  Do

  If InStr(Look.Cells(c.Row, "D"), "SUBSTRING&#0174") > 0 _
  Or InStr(Look.Cells(c.Row, "D"), "SUBSTRING®") > 0 _
  Or InStr(Look.Cells(c.Row, "D"), "SUBSTRINGÂ®") > 0 Then
  Look.Cells(c.Row, "C") = 1
  End If

  Set c = .FindNext(c)

  If c Is Nothing Then
  GoTo DoneFinding
  End If

  Loop While c.Address <> firstaddress
  End If

DoneFinding:
  End With

End Sub
```